PHP Exec gives error when trying to convert videos on my site
I keep getting this error below when using PHP's exec command:
**'-i' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
**operable program or batch file.**
**Upload failed**

I'm making my own mini Youtube site as a fun project for starting. I have become stuck because at this particular point I cant seem to run an exec in order to convert the video format.
I think the problem is this part here:
$cmd = "$this->ffmpegPath -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1";

As it is used in my function's code:
public function convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath) 
{ 
    $cmd = "$this->ffmpegPath -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1";

    $outputLog = array();
    exec($cmd, $outputLog, $returnCode);

    if($returnCode != 0) 
    {
        //Command failed
        foreach($outputLog as $line) 
        { echo $line . "<br>"; }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

Question:
Is it possible that the problem comes trying to upload a file which is already in MP4 format the reason it wont upload? Does it need to be in format, (eg: MP3 for example), in order to re-convert it to MP4?
I tried looking through my code for grammatical errors, but the code seems ok I just cant get past this error message mentioned above.

While you wait... (1) Research your problem for checking any past solutions that worked for others. (2) According to the FFmpeg documentation, you should be using shell_exec to run their program (not using exec). On that page, look/search for the this line Let's consider the natural way to run ffmpeg from PHP scripts and read onwards from there...
